# Error converting value "{"1":"1","3":"1"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I am using C# Newtonsoft.Json to serialize and deserialize data.
I serialaized my class that have dictionary, and when I try to deserialize it I get error:

```
Error converting value "{"1":"1","3":"1"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
```

Json looks like:

```
[{
    "id": "4",
    "provider": "1",
    "items_id_num_json": "{\"1\":\"1\",\"3\":\"1\"}",
    "creator": "",
    "creation_time": "10.04.2016 19:00:25",
    "deleted": "0"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "provider": "1",
    "items_id_num_json": "{\"1\":\"1\"}",
    "creator": "",
    "creation_time": "10.04.2016 18:12:01",
    "deleted": "0"
}]
```

Class:

```
public class Supply
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string deleted { get; set; }
    public string provider { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> items_id_num_json { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public string creation_time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well in your JSON, `items_id_num_json` is a String (with escape characters). Your JSON should look like: `"items_id_num_json":{"1":"1","3":"1"}` afaik.

Comment: go here [Json to C# Class Converter](http://json2csharp.com/) and generate your class, try your JSON after using the class and see if it works..

Comment: Actually string looks like:
`"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"receiver\":\"1\",\"items_id_num_json\":\"{\\\"1\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"3\\\":\\\"1\\\"}\",\"creator\":\"\",\"creation_time\":\"10.04.2016 19:39:15\",\"deleted\":\"0\"}]"`

I used command:
`answer.Replace("\\\"","\"");`

Then string looks like:
`"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"receiver\":\"1\",\"items_id_num_json\":\"{\"1\":\"1\",\"3\":\"2\"}\",\"creator\":\"\",\"creation_time\":\"10.04.2016 19:39:15\",\"deleted\":\"0\"}]"`
And error:
`Error converting value "{" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your `"items_id_num_json"` property is actually a string primitive whose contents are embedded, escaped JSON containing an already-serialized `Dictionary<int, int>`.   Given that the property name ends in `_json` I reckon this was intentional on the part of the sending system and not a mistake.

In order to access the dictionary contents, you need to make a nested call to [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) like so:

```
public class Supply
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string deleted { get; set; }
    public string provider { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> items_id_num { get; set; }

    public string items_id_num_json
    {
        get
        {
            if (items_id_num == null)
                return null;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items_id_num);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                items_id_num = null;
            else
                items_id_num = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
        }
    }

    public string creator { get; set; }
    public string creation_time { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
var supplyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Supply>>(jsonString);
```